# QGIS software missing on laptop after trying to update to latest version

Tags: qgis-3, installation, windows

I am facing an issue with QGIS installation. I tried to upgrade my QGIS to version QGIS 3.14, I couldn't locate it on my laptop anymore. However, I can see it in the uninstall section of my laptop. I have tried uninstalling it and re-installing it back, yet, I am still faced with same problem.

Following the file path I created during the installation, I found the QGIS 3.14 folder on my 'program files', but didn't find a shortcut icon. I saw and run the `qgiscrashhandler.exe`, but a System error pop-up tells me that `Qt5Widgets.dll, Qt5Gui.dll, Qt5Core.dll were not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.` I have reinstalled and redownloaded QGIS software countless times, yet the issue subsists.

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: You could try the OSGeo4W installer: https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ It allows you to update QGIS without having to uninstall the previous version.

Comment: I think in windows it should be in C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.14\BIN\qgis-bin.exe  I can't be completely sure because I am currently using the OSGeo4W network installer. Also available on QGIS downloads page: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html It installs here - C:\OSGeo4W64\bin just in case you unknowingly installed it using the OSGEO.  Sometimes I find I have to restart my computer before it registers and shows up in my windows search.